# How to give it more time to call the API from a client application in C#

Tags: c#, rest, async-await

I have an application in windforms, which calls an API in .net, but gives the following error:
The request was cancelled due to the configured `HttpClient.Timeout` of 100 seconds elapsing.

This is because on the client side, where I make the request, has a time limit. Since in the API, it takes a long time due to a process that acts as communication.

This is the code from the client, which calls the API:

```
  public string llamar_api_khipu(string tipobanco,
    string host,
    string user,
    string dataBase,
    string puerto,
    string passworddb,
    string codigobanco,
    string UserName,
    string Password,
    string EnterpriseIdentity,
    string Role,
    string Agreement,
    string accountNumber,
    string BookingDateStart,
    string BookingDateEnd)
{

    string respuesta = "";
    Respuesta obj_result = Task.Run(() => respuestaJson(tipobanco,
     host,
     user,
     dataBase,
     puerto,
     passworddb,
     codigobanco,
     UserName,
     Password,
     EnterpriseIdentity,
     Role,
     Agreement,
     accountNumber,
     BookingDateStart,
     BookingDateEnd)).Result;

    respuesta = obj_result.datos;
    return respuesta;
}


public async Task<Respuesta> respuestaJson(string tipobanco,
    string host,
    string user,
    string dataBase,
    string puerto,
    string passworddb,
    string codigobanco,
    string UserName,
    string Password,
    string EnterpriseIdentity,
    string Role,
    string Agreement,
    string accountNumber,
    string BookingDateStart,
    string BookingDateEnd)
{
    string urlApi = $"http://localhost:17649/obtienerespuestakhipu?tipobanco={tipobanco}&host={host}" +
        $"&user={user}&dataBase={dataBase}&puerto={puerto}&passworddb={passworddb}&codigobanco={codigobanco}" +
        $"&UserName={UserName}&Password={Password}&EnterpriseIdentity={EnterpriseIdentity}&Role={Role}" +
        $"&Agreement={Agreement}&accountNumber={accountNumber}&BookingDateStart={BookingDateStart}&BookingDateEnd={BookingDateEnd}";
    Respuesta resp = new Respuesta();


    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        try
        {
            ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 80;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            HttpResponseMessage respuesta = await httpClient.GetAsync(urlApi);

            if (respuesta.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                // Leer y deserializar el contenido JSON
                string contenidoJson = await respuesta.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var datosDeserializados = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Respuesta>(contenidoJson);

                resp.datos = datosDeserializados.datos;

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error en la llamada a la API. Código de estado: {respuesta.StatusCode}");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }


        return resp;
}
```

I wanted to know how to give more time to the client. I tried to use `DefaultConnectionLimit` , but still, it gives me the error.

Comment: Set the `httpClient.Timeout` property to the TimeSpan you want. For example: `httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);`